# Proguard does not obfuscate gui components

Tags: android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, proguard

I would like to use ProGuard to obfuscate my Android app. This works fine. But my gui classes, which extends acitvity, view and sherlockactivity are not obfuscated. Here is the proguard.cfg

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars C:/Users/android-sdks/platforms/android-17/android.jar


-dontpreverify
-dontoptimize
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizationpasses 5
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn    sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn    com.actionbarsherlock.**
-dontwarn    com.google.common.**

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
-keep public class * extends android.view.ViewGroup
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
public void *(android.view.View);
}
-keepclassmembers class android.support.v4.app.Fragment { 
*** getActivity(); 
public *** onCreate(); 
public *** onCreateOptionsMenu(...); 
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock {
public <init>(...); 
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}


-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
   public <init>(android.content.Context);
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
   public void set*(...);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class com.brainyoo.brainyoo2android.ui.html.BYJavaScriptInterface {
   public *;
}
```

First, I thought activities can´t be obfuscated because of the reflection call

```
myactivity.class
```

I've tried to add:

```
- keep public class mypackege.myactivity.class
```

But it does not solve the problem. Any ideas how to obfuscate the gui elements?

Thanks
Christine

Comment: How did you determine that your GUI classes were not obfuscated?

Comment: I think it is a known issue with `actionbarsherlock`

Comment: I did determine that my GUI classes were not obfuscated, because after obfusecating my app, I used the dex2jar disassembler to get a jar file of my apk. Then I used a java decompiler with a gui. There I can see that all my classes were obfuscated, except my GUI classes

Answer (score 4):

> But my gui classes, which extends acitvit, view and sherlockactivtiy are not obfusecated.

That is because your ProGuard configuration file says to not obfuscate them. Moreover, this is important, as if they *are* obfuscated, your app will not run, because:

- Android will not find your renamed activities
- Android will not find your activity lifecycle methods
- Android will not find your widgets (for use with reflection in interpreting layout resources)
- etc.

> I´ve tried to added: `-keep public class mypackege.myactivity.class` But it does not solve the problem.

That is because you are telling ProGuard to *not* obfuscate that class.

> Any ideas how to obfusecate the gui elements?

You don't, if you wish to have a working app when you are done.

Comment: @ChristineBauers The most important part of this answer is telling you to _not_ even try to obfuscate your Activity. You could change the rules to get it done, but then Android would not be able to find your lifecycle methods, which would at best leave your activity unusable, and at worst might cause application-crashing exceptions.

Comment: If you are not referencing your views from XML, it´s totally okay to obfuscate them. No problem at all