# Tell Proguard to obfuscate Fragment classes

Tags: android, proguard

How can I obfuscate Fragment classes in my android app using Proguard? Now it is not obfuscating Fragment classes along with activities and others. I want fragment classes to be obfuscated. How can I do that?

Comment: Post your proguard file please

Comment: You may find this post usefull for what you're trying https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501132/should-i-keep-android-support-v4-app-fragment-and-its-derived-classes-when-build